# Convert a datatime with milliseconds from a given data and a fiven fractional seconds

Tags: python, datetime, date-format, milliseconds

I have a given data, for example:

```
"2021-12-01 12:00:00" (i.e., %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)
```

and a given millisecond: `3599.9`. I wish to add this millisecond to the previus date in order to have the following format:

`%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f` or `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f`

I found some example, but all starting with `datetime.utcnow()`. For example:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> (dt, micro) = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').split('.')
>>> "%s.%03d" % (dt, int(micro) / 1000)
'2016-02-26 04:37:53.133'
```

Comment: in essence you could use: `(datetime.fromisoformat("2021-12-01 12:00:00")+timedelta(milliseconds=3599.9)).isoformat(" ", timespec="microseconds")`

Comment: Is this related to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76619556/10197418)? If so, consider doing it in pandas exclusively. That way, it will be much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you could achieve that:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Your initial date and time as a string
time_str = "2021-12-01 12:00:00"

# Convert the string to a datetime object
time_dt = datetime.strptime(time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

# Milliseconds to add
milliseconds = 3599.9

# Convert the milliseconds to a timedelta and add it to the datetime
time_dt += timedelta(milliseconds=milliseconds)

# Convert the datetime back to a string
new_time_str = time_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]  # The [:-3] trims the last three digits to give milliseconds precision

print(new_time_str)
```

Comment: I suppose milliseconds = 3599.9 is not milliseconds but fraction of seconds and timedelta(seconds=...)

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand that. 3599.9 are the milliseconds that you want to add to your timestamp, which is being done in the example. Can you tell me what exactly is unclear?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).